# Create new column in pandas DataFrame based in date sequences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a column in a `pd.DataFrame` using date sequences defined in another dataset.

I've come up with the solution below, but I'd like to know if there is a more pythonic and also faster way to do it.

The sample data frames:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "start": pd.date_range(start="1/1/2022", end="1/5/2022", freq="D"),
    "stop": pd.date_range(start="1/2/2022", end="1/6/2022", freq="D"),
    "seq_id": np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], size=5)
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "V1": np.random.randint(1, 10, 121),
    "seq_id": str()
}, index=pd.date_range(start="1/1/2022", end="1/6/2022", freq="H"))
```

And the current solution:

```py
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df2.loc[df1.start[i]:df1.stop[i], "seq_id"] = df1.seq_id[i]
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

just try this instead of your for loop:

```
df2["seq_id"] = df1.seq_id.values
```

Comment: Ok, that works because both df1 and df2 have the same length, but It wouldn't be in a particular case. If df2 takes a different frequency or spans for a more extended period. I'm editing my question to better match this condition